# WebPack React - Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I've checked every other question and none seem to provide an answer that work for me.

Getting this error when attempting to compile:

```
  27 |
  28 |   return (
> 29 |     <G x={logoPosition} y={logoPosition}>
     |     ^
  30 |       <Defs>
  31 |         <ClipPath id='clip-logo-background'>
  32 |           <Rect

Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

This is the code that is causing it:

```
import * as React from "react";
import WalletConnectProvider from "@walletconnect/react-native-dapp";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

export default function WalletConnector() {
    return (
        <WalletConnectProvider
            bridge="https://bridge.walletconnect.org"
            clientMeta={{
                description: "Connect with WalletConnect",
                url: "https://walletconnect.org",
                icons: ["https://walletconnect.org/walletconnect-logo.png"],
                name: "WalletConnect",
            }}
            redirectUrl={window.location.origin}
            storageOptions={{
                asyncStorage: AsyncStorage as any,
            }}
        >
            <>{/* awesome app here */}</>
        </WalletConnectProvider>
    );
}
```

This is the package causing it: "@walletconnect/react-native-dapp": "^1.4.1"

I've added `.babelrc` with the following and problem persists.

```
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

I've also added babel.confis.json which didn't help and added a babel section in my `package.json` with the proper plugins/presets and still no change.

Answer (score 0):

For bare CLI project update below files.

Reference: https://github.com/WalletConnect/walletconnect-monorepo/issues/753

Update metro-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    extraNodeModules: require("node-libs-react-native")
  },
  . . . 
};
```

Add following statement in index.js

```
require("node-libs-react-native/globals.js");
```